# How to stub this method with mockito

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I am using Mockito on kotlin class

```
androidTestImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"
```

The method looks like this:

```
open class A {
  open fun doSomething(text: String, text1: String, callback:(Boolean)-> Unit) {
    ...
  }

}
```

I tried stubbing it the following way:

```
 mock<A>() {
   on { doSomething(any(),any(), any())}.then {
         it.arguemnts.last().invoke(true)
    }
 }
```

But it fails on NPE:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
```

How to fix it?

Comment: which mocking framework is that?

Comment: see edited answer please

Comment: which line of code is the NPE referring to?

Comment: the third any(), it is a variable of type (Boolean) -> Unit

Comment: in a different location () -> Unit works just fine

Comment: Try to give the type to the any object: `on { doSomething(any(),any(), any<(Boolean) -> Unit>()) }`

Comment: I tried that, that didnt work